# URL Rewriting for better Search Engine Optimization

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I am working on ASP.NET website.
I need to post a Question Paper based on following parameters.

- University
- Branch
- Subject

At Present My URL is in the below mentioned format

> //localhost/MYASP/Posted?PostId=**

My URL should be in the below mention format after URL Rewriting

> //localhost/MYASP/Posted/University/Branch/Subject/TITLEOFThePost

And also please let me know the process of finding my querystring after url rewriting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use an URL of the format

```
//localhost/MYASP/Posted/ID/University/Branch/Subject/TITLEOFThePost
```

That way you can simply rewrite the URL using just the ID and the University / Branch / Subject can all be tossed.

Answer (score 0):

Source: http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/11/advanced-url-rewriting-for-rest-of-us.html

Read all of that. This is not a simple question with a simple answer. However, that blog will detail a lot of information for you.